# How to set fixed hashCode-Value in Unit-Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

as I am writing a unit-test for a bug in the order of some multimap we are using, I am looking for a way to have the hashCode fix 'injected' in the unit-test.

Is there any way to override the default-hashCode()-value without changing the original class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried looking at Powermock?

Comment: may be u can extend your class under `test`, and override hashCode method, and use the new class in ur test

Comment: Sajan Chandran: Thanks for the idea. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Create a derived class that overrides the GetHashCode method. Declare any constructors and call the equivalent base (). Use this class to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class that implements the hashcode shall implement an Interface, The objects added to the multimap should be of that Interface. In the unit test you create a new class where you can set the desired return value of hashcode. Then add these testobjects to the multimap.

```
MultiMap<IMyObjects> multimap;


class MyTestObjects implements IMyObjects {
private int hashCodeToUse = 42;

public int hashCode() {
  return hashCodeToUse;
}

// TODO write setter for hashCodetoUse
}

public void testHashCode() {
  // TODO init multipam
  MyTestObject obj1 = new MyTestObject();
  obj1.setHashCodeToUse(234);
  multimap.put(obj1);
}
```

Comment: I think it's the right direction, I'll just have to adapt it to our project-structure. Thanks!